# Entity Framework Migration "No connection string named 'DefaultConnection' could be found..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been working with MVC5 and Entity Framework 6 for the past few months.  I have separated my main models/business logic and "Migrations" to a separate assembly and referenced it in my web application.  Migrations have been working just fine.

Today I ran "Update-database" and I get "No connection string named 'DefaultConnection' could be found in the application config file."

The 'DefaultConnection' is STILL in my web.config file.  If I copy the  section to the project where the Migrations are located, it works again.  If I remove the  section, it throws that error.  I don't know what might have changed.

The only thing I did since yesterday was run "Disk Cleanup" to clear up space on my HD.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Okay.  After some obscure Google searches I found the answer.  Apparently my project containing the Migration code was set as the "Startup Project".

After resetting my web application as the Startup Project (and making sure the 'Default Project' in the Package Manager is set to my Migrations project), it started working again!

Problem solved!

Comment: thanks this was driving me nuts as this happened to me today as well

Comment: And just to clarify that's not a Package Manager Console command, just as normal right click an appropriate start project and choose `Set as Startup Prioject`.

Comment: Had a similar problem - EF classes are in another project.  But the same project that was set as startup had to be set as Startup, and the EF project as DefaultProject in the package manager console to get it to work.

Comment: Confirmed this fixed it for me.  Thanks for figuring this out.  Saved me hours.

Comment: I had the same problem spring up.  The Startup Project was a different project.  I had to set the project with the migrations to be the Startup to get my `Add-Migration` to work.  We'll see whether next time I have to set it back to the previous Startup Project!  (All projects other than the project with the migrations are unit test projects.)

Comment: Saved my day. I manage 3 context projects with 2 startup projects and this was the first time that I tried to add a migration to a context while having the wrong startup project active.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am intrigued as to WHY migration does not work if the EF project being migrated is the Startup Project. Any ideas? My guess is that this happens only when this is a Class Library. If it is an App (Console/Web App), it won't have this issue. Will try to confirm this soon.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the execution of a command from Nuget console you choose the right project
[image]

Comment: I have the correct Default project chosen.  Same error.

Comment: See my answer below.  I found the problem.